# OR-TOOLS google how to tell the solver to stop when reaching a certain result

Tags: python, or-tools

I have a simple 3d assignment problem.
I'm randomly generating integer numbers between 0 and 100 for a cost matrix.

I've noticed that when the size of the problem is large enough say 40 assigments.(40X40X40 cost matrix).The total cost reaches 0. which makes sense.

as the matrix grows bigger I assume there are more ways to reach the desired results and I Don't expect the solve time to rise exponentially.
But id does.

I assume this is because the algorithm isn't satisficed with a zero result until it is absolutely sure its optimal.

My question is is there a way to tell the solver to stop when it reaches a certain total cost?
I haven't found that option in the docs

when I try to limit the time

```py
solver.SetTimeLimit(TIME)
```

the solver simply cant find a solution.

I tried adding the constraint suggested in one of the answers (total cost>=0) but it had no effect.

when adding the following line for a 20X20X20 problem

```py
solver.Add(solver.Objective().Value() >= 1)
```

the solver cant find a solution
but when adding

```py
solver.Add(solver.Objective().Value() >= 0)
```

it find a solution with total cost of 4 why can't it find the same solution with the first constraint?

and how do I tell it to stop when reaching 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 solver.Add(solver.Objective().Value() >= 0)
```

does not do what you expect. solver.Objective() is a class of type MPObjective. Calling Value() on it checks is a solution has been found, and returns 0 if this is not the case.

So in practice, you are executing:

```
solver.Add(0 >= 0)
```

which is a no op.

In order to limit the objective, you should create one integer variable `new_var` from 0 to `sum(cost_coefficients)`, then add `new_var = sum(cost_coefficients * bool_vars)`, and finally minimize `new_var`.

Comment: Personally, I would use CP-SAT, but I am biased.

Comment: cp sat took way longer it couldn't solve 30 x 30 x30 in a reasonable time

Comment: '''y = solver.IntVar(0, solver.infinity, '')''' '''y = sum(objective_terms)''' '''solver.Minimize(y)''' this code simlpy runs over y how do i keep y as an intvar?

Comment: you create it as an intvar.

Comment: i did but when i write y = sum(objective_terms) it gets overwritten

Comment: Don't make the same mistake as above. variable are solver objects.  You need to write `solver.Add(new_var == sum(objective_terms))`

Comment: thank you very much it works slower on the small problem but way faster on the large ones how do i close the question?

Comment: Approve my answer. So that it is visible that it was answered.

Comment: the old solution time for a problem of size 70 was 533 the new one took 1916 seconds for a problem of size 60 the old problem took 400 seconds the new one takes 233 seconds why does it act so weird?

Comment: Luck. On one instance, time variability is very high. You need lot of instances to build confidence whether a model is better than another.

Comment: I feel like your in your solution the algorithm isn't sure what its doing because we never tell it what y is so that its based on luck. is there another way to do the early stopping?

Comment: Can you try with SAT_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING, using MPSolver.SetNumThreads(8) ?

Comment: I'm using python not sure what u mean what solver u want me to import I don't see anything talking about threads in the documentation

Comment: When constructing the solver, you pass an enum or a string description. Most likely 'cbc' or CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING. Please try with 'sat' or SAT_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING. Furthermore, you can specify the number of threads to use in the solver with this api: http://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/linear_solver/pywraplp.html#pywraplp.Solver.SetNumThreads . The CP-SAT backend benefits greatly from 8 threads.

Comment: Using sat was way slower but when i switched to glop solver my results sky rocketed for a problem of 80 on 80 it took 41 seconds to solve while both the other solvers took more than an hour

Comment: These are not the same solvers at all. GLOP is a simplex. It will ignore any integrality constraint (var needs to have an integer value in the solution). CP-SAT does not ignore those. GLOP complexity is pseudo-polynomial, CP-SAT is NP-Hard. In your particular case, it may be possible that the problem is unimodular, that is any optinal solution with GLOP is actually integer. But please check that this is the case.

Comment: I got myself an academic license for  Gurobi  and solved with Gurobi  using binary vars. the speed is amazing. The only problem is that I'm working for a company and ill probably have to get a license to use it in our products, is there something like Gurobi which is free?

Comment: sadly the sat solver with 8 threads has very similar speed to the CBC

Comment: is there a way to force glop to use binary variables like in gurobi?

Comment: Not glop is a simplex. Gurobi is an exceptional commercial mip solver.

Comment: thank you the sat with 8 threads is better then the CBC and is what I am using now thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

there is a link to solution - https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1439

You need to set RoutingMonitor Class and connect with AddAtSolutionCallback.

```
def make_routing_monitor(routing_model: pywrapcp.RoutingModel, stop_objective: int, failure_limit: int) -> callable:
    
    class RoutingMonitor:
        def __init__(self, model: pywrapcp.RoutingModel):
            self.model = model
            self._counter = 0
            self._best_objective = float('inf')
            self._counter_limit = failure_limit
            self._stop_objective = stop_objective

        def __call__(self):
            if self._stop_objective==self.model.CostVar().Min():
                self.model.solver().FinishCurrentSearch()
    
                        
    return RoutingMonitor(routing_model)
```

And connect to the solver:

```
routing_monitor = make_routing_monitor(routing, data['total_distance'] ,0)
routing.AddAtSolutionCallback(routing_monitor)

solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
```